# Null Value on foreign key using OneToOne Relationship

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

The code is working except for the NULL value on person_id in Resume table.
I can't figure out how to set value to it.
I try this :

```
$resume->setPerson($person); --> not working.
```

\AppBundle\Entity\Person

```
class Person
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Resume", mappedBy="person", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $resume;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return Person
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set resume
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Resume $resume
 *
 * @return Person
 */
public function setResume(\AppBundle\Entity\Resume $resume = null)
{
    $this->resume = $resume;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get resume
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Resume
 */
public function getResume()
{
    return $this->resume;
}
}
```

\AppBundle\Entity\Resume

```
class Resume
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
private $address;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="resume")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $person;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set address
 *
 * @param string $address
 *
 * @return Resume
 */
public function setAddress($address)
{
    $this->address = $address;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get address
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAddress()
{
    return $this->address;
}

/**
 * Set person
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Person $person
 *
 * @return Resume
 */
public function setPerson(\AppBundle\Entity\Person $person = null)
{
    $this->person = $person;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get person
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Person
 */
public function getPerson()
{
    return $this->person;
}
}
```

\AppBundle\Controller\PersonController

```
class PersonController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/person/new", name="person_new")
 *
 */
public function createProductAction(Request $request)
{
    $person = new Person();

    $resume = new Resume();
    $resume->setPerson($person);


    $form = $this->createForm(PersonType::class, $person);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($person);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render(
        'person/new.html.twig',
        array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        )
    );
}
```

/person/new.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$resume->setPerson($this);` in your `setResume`. Right now you don't have any piece of code that would update a person for resume, since you're editing person (not resume) in your controller.

```
/**
 * Set resume
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Resume $resume
 *
 * @return Person
 */
public function setResume(\AppBundle\Entity\Resume $resume = null)
{
    $resume->setPerson($this);
    $this->resume = $resume;

    return $this;
}
```